# What are the different ways to represent quote character in java in a string literal?

Tags: java, arrays, string, character

So a googler asked this question, as what are the different ways you can represent a character (in this case the double quote) in JAVA.

One being

```
String t ="\\u0022";
```

What are the other ways ?

Comment: I doubt the question was formulated that way. Your code (`String t ="\u0022";`) doesn't compile, because \u0022 stands for a double quote at source code level, so it's 100% equivalent to `String t = """;` which mean: 3 double quotes in a row, which is invalid. See also the JLS section 3.10.5: [*Finally, it is not possible to write "\u0022" for a string literal containing a double quotation mark (").*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)

Answer (score 2):

In Java, one can escape literal quotes like

```
String t = "\"";
```

and with the unicode escape you already gave (with another literal `\` because the unicode conversion happens very early in the compilation phase)

```
String t = "\\u0022";
```

and you can promote a character like

```
String t = Character.toString('"');
```

Comment: See my comment on the question: `String t = "\u0022";` isn't valid Java: it results in compile error "String literal is not properly closed by double quote". Change it to `String t = "\\u0022";`

Answer (score 0):

The two other way are:

1. An escape character followed by a double quote: `\"`,
2. The unicode example given: `\u0022`,
3. And by converting a char to a string: `new Character('"').toString();`.

The first one is the simplest, and easiest on the programmer, the second is longer, and generally harder to remember, and the third is easy to remember but generally illogical.

Comment: 3 is not illogical.  It's just a mouthful. :P

Comment: That's why its illogical :)